# How to identify client in twisted?

Tags: python, connection, client, protocols, twisted

I'm connecting to server over two different ports 50000 and 20000. I will write some data over one and sometimes over another one and respectively I will get a response. How I could do this correctly? Do I need create some reference in twisted ClientFactory subclass? Here is my code sample:

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)


class PrimeClient(object):
   """
   """
   def __init__(self):
      """
      """
      self.factory = PrimeClientFactory()

   def connect(self):

      servers = [('192.168.110.14', 50000),('192.168.110.14', 20000)]

      for host, port in servers:            
        reactor.connectTCP(host, port, self.factory)



class PrimeProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Connection made: {} {}'.format(self, self.factory)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'RCV: {}'.format(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Connection lost: {}'.format(reason)



class PrimeClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    """
    """
    protocol = PrimeProtocol

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed: {} - {}'.format(connector, reason)

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started connection: {}'.format(connector)



def main():
    prime = PrimeClient()

    prime.connect()
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will create two connections to server. So how I could identify connection, if, in example, I want to send to port 50000?

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a global dict/list to hold connections, and add/remove connection to/from it in `connectionMade()/connectionLost()`.

Or you may use [ClientCreator](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ClientCreator.html#connectTCP) for convienence

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using global's, but nice suggestion. I will look at ClientCreator and think how could I use it it my communication. Where will be an API who will send and receive data over these connections, so in general this twisted will serve as something like transport...

Comment: Indeed, don't use globals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [frequently asked question](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother) about Twisted.

The simplest solution is to make a `connections` list on `PrimeClientFactory` and do `self.factory.connections.append(self)` in `connectionMade` and `self.factory.connections.remove(self)` in `connectionLost` on `PrimeProtocol`.

(Also, `ClientFactory` and `connectTCP` are somewhat outdated ways of doing this, you should really [use the much newer "endpoints" API for clients instead](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/endpoints.html).)

Comment: Right now I'm reading this post:)... The main purpose why I'm not using connection list, because the first connection is so called "management" port and other is "data transfer" port. So I need a more clear way to use them, and treat them differently (differently with data content). Maybe I need separate protocols and factories... but I think it's redundant.